# React native - assemble release apk

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm trying to assemble a release APK to test the app on another Android phone, and being blocked by following error.

```
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':reactnativenotifications:reactNative60DebugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not download mockito-core-2.25.1.jar (org.mockito:mockito-core:2.25.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/mockito-core-2.25.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/mockito-core-2.25.1.jar'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not download shadows-framework-4.3.jar (org.robolectric:shadows-framework:4.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/robolectric/shadows-framework/4.3/shadows-framework-4.3.jar'.
         > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 3,329,584; received: 289,045)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you connected to internet ? As error says process not able to download some libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Open your build.gradle file and add the code below under android:

```
android {

    lintOptions { 
      checkReleaseBuilds false 
 }
```